# Troubleshoot of "az functionapp deployment source config-zip" in github actions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions, azure-deployment

I have a simple azure function app that I want to deploy via github pages, I'm trying to do it via: `az functionapp deployment source config-zip`. This works well from my local windows machine:

```
 C:\%APP_DEMO%>az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g WebApiDemoResourceGroup -n FunctionAppInstance1 --src functionapp.zip
```

but when I do it on github action like:

```
  buildFunction:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: prepareAzure
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: functionapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

  deployFunction:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: buildFunction
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: functionapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.47.0
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal \
          -u ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} \
          -p ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }} \
          -t ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_TENANT_ID }}        
    - name: Deploy to Azure Function
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.47.0
        inlineScript: |
          zip -r functionapp.zip .
          groupName=${{ env.AZURE_GROUP_NAME }}
          az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $groupName -n ${{env.AZURE_FUNCTION_NAME}} --src functionapp.zip
```

I see that `deployFunction` step is **not** failed, but in logs I see:

```
Run azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    azcliversion: 2.47.0
    inlineScript: zip -r functionapp.zip .
  groupName=%MyRG%
  az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $groupName -n %APP_NAME% --src functionapp.zip
  
  env:
    AZURE_GROUP_NAME: %MyRG%
    AZURE_LOCATION: southcentralus
    AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: WebApiDemoWebApp
    AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: WebApiDemo/publish
    CONFIGURATION: Release
    DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
    WORKING_DIRECTORY: WebApiDemo
    FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY: %APP_DEMO%
    AZURE_FUNCTION_NAME: %APP_NAME%
    AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: %APP_DEMO%/published
Error: Please use Linux based OS as a runner.
Warning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\a\_temp'
cleaning up container...
```

how can I troubleshoot it? Even though the whole step is not failed, I don't see my deployed function on the portal.

Operating system I used for my fuction is Windows. I see it in the portal overview page:

```
Operating System
Windows
```

same I see in service plan:

```
Operating System
:
Windows
```

It might be related to this [guard](https://github.com/Azure/cli/blob/master/src/main.ts#LL20C14-L20C14), but I have no ideas what it does mean.

Comment: Did you try with Linux OS?

Comment: What is a typical/standard way to deploy functions? I'm beginner in azure and surprised to see such base error in very first steps..

Comment: @PravallikaKV, I have azure function and web app in my resource group, if I switch azure function to linux, I see this error when I create web app (even before creating fuction): `"message":"Linux dynamic workers are not available in resource group WebApiDemoResourceGroup. Use this link to`. Something weird is going on..

Comment: Try: `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have azure function and web app in my resource group, if I switch azure function to linux, I see this error when I create web app (even before creating fuction): `"message":"Linux dynamic workers are not available in resource group WebApiDemoResourceGroup. Use this link to`. Something weird is going on..

I found few similar cases where in users facing the same issue. This seems to be a limitation.

1. [Issue 1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36268)
2. [Issue 2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43248)

- Create a new resource group and try to create linux function app in that particular resource group in a different region.
- Try to deploy your function app using GitHub-actions:
- As, @*Azeem* mentioned, change `runs-on:windows` to `runs-on:ubuntu` in your workflow and deploy.

```yaml
 buildFunction:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: prepareAzure
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.FUNCTION_WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: functionapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

  deployFunction:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: buildFunction
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: functionapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.47.0
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal \
          -u ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} \
          -p ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }} \
          -t ${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_TENANT_ID }}        
    - name: Deploy to Azure Function
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.47.0
        inlineScript: |
          zip -r functionapp.zip .
          groupName=${{ env.AZURE_GROUP_NAME }}
          az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $groupName -n ${{env.AZURE_FUNCTION_NAME}} --src functionapp.zip
```

***Alternative:***

As you are facing issue while creating *linux* function app, you can try other way to deploy the function to *windows* function app.

- Deploy via deployment center through Azure portal using GitHub actions.
  By this way, you can deploy your function app as ***zip package***.

Go to your function app in Azure portal=>Deployment=>Deployment center=> Settings=>

- Select *GitHub* as *source* and provide the details of all other fields and save.
  [image]
- Once you click on save, it starts the deployment.
- To check the deployment status, click on main=>It will be redirected to github=>click on Actions.
  [image]

***As shown below, GitHub actions deploys the function app using zip deployment.***

[image]

Comment: the auto script also uses publishing profile: `publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_8a9f1957c... }}`. I was under impression that just using creds (like access_id, secret_key, tenant) everywhere is a better option instead of generating such profile for each application

Comment: Are you still facing issue?

Comment: it works if I use `publish-profile` like `name: 'Run Azure Functions Action' / uses: Azure/functions-action@v1 / id: fa / with: / app-name: 'FunctionAppInstance1' / slot-name: 'Production' / package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output' / publish-profile: ...` (I can generate it with VS or as you suggested via azure portal), but I would prefer to use azure cli with providing arguments separately like I did initially: `az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $groupName -n ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTION_NAME }} --src function.zip`. That one doesn't work.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, try creating linux function app in new resource group and use the workflow which I have given above, you will be able to deploy.